# Bluetooth Low Energy Discovery JAVA2SE

Tags: java, bluetooth, service-discovery, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to  discover a BLE device with JAVA2SE, I searched a lot on google and I couldn't find any libraries or ideas about how I would be able to discover this device.

Android has bluegatt, so I assume there is a possibility to do this.

Have you guys any kind of idea to get around those problems.

Hope you guys will be able to help me !

**Found solution in Python**

Joseph Gremaud

Answer (score 0):

One quick google search got me here:

> https://github.com/movisens/SmartGattLib

Comment: its said that compability is only on mobile languages ! You went to quickly ^^ !

Comment: Any SMART stack. It's a bluetooth standard.

Comment: Ok didnt know that I'll try to test some things in this direction thank you !

Comment: Just tested smartGattLib is exclusivly made for Android !